# How to transform a long number to jsonelement with gson in java

Tags: java

```
JsonElement value = entry.getValue();
value = value.getAsLong() * 1000;
```

It will throw error that incompatible types. How to transform `value` to jsonelement?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to recreate a `JsonElement` with the new calculated value, then replace it in the entry :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

JsonElement value = entry.getValue();
JsonElement newElement = gson.toJsonTree(value.getAsLong() * 1000);
entry.setValue(newElement);
```

Comment: This is a solution, but I did it in another way in the end. Like `value = new JsonPrimitive(value.getAsLong() * 1000);`. It also worked. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Indeed your solution looks smarter. I will leave this answer anyway, along with your comment it may help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used this to convert a JSON Number to a long, maybe it is useful to someone:

```
class OrdersDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<OrdersResponse.Orders> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): OrdersResponse.Orders {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject

        val total = jsonObject.get("total").asNumber.toLong()
        jsonObject.add("total", JsonPrimitive(total))

        return Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, OrdersResponse.Orders::class.java)
    }
}
```